# add data to the database from a class

Tags: java, android, database, android-room, dao

hello can I add data in the databse DAO from a class, or can I do it only from the mainthread?For example, if i have Database DAO:

```
public interface UserDAO {
    @Query("select*from User")
    List<User> getAll();
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertAll(User...users);
   
}
```

and i have Appdatabase.class:

```
@Database(entities = {User.class},version=1)
public abstract  class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract UserDAO userDAO();
}
```

i also have a class that initializes the DAO database:

```
Model_user {
 public static synchronized Model_user getInstance() {
        if (theinstance == null) {

            theinstance = new Model_user();
        }
        return theinstance;
    }

    public static synchronized Model_user getInstance(Context c) {
        if (theinstance == null) {
            userDAOs = Room.databaseBuilder(c, AppDatabase.class, "userdb").build();
            theinstance = new Model_user();
        }
        return theinstance;
    }

    private Model_user() {
        user_list = new ArrayList<User>();
    }
    public void addUsers(User[] s) {
        Log.d("main_activity_uid", "ok it start");
        userDAOs.userDAO().insertAll(s);
        user_list.addAll(Arrays.asList(s));
        Log.d("main_activity_uid", "ok");
        return;
    }
```

Now in Utils.class , i can't add data;in Utils.class i have:

```
Model_user.getInstance(activity.getApplicationContext()).addUsers(u.toArray(new User[0]));
```

for store data in DAO database,but but it does not start.Why?How can i do? can i add data to the DAO database only from the main activity?

Comment: *i can't add data* - why not? Are you maybe getting an error, what error?

Comment: `@Query("select*from User")` is this correct?  Are not some spaces needed?